# SwiperSlider, Gallery with thumbs and loop enabled breaks SwiperSlider completly

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-cli, swiper.js

SwiperSlider breaks with loop: true and thumbs enabled.

my code is this:

```
var galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
  spaceBetween: 15,
  slidesPerView: 2,
  centeredSlides: true,
  loop: true
});

var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
  spaceBetween: 10,
  centeredSlides: true,
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  touchRatio: 0.2,
  slideToClickedSlide: true,
  loop: true
});

galleryTop.params.control = galleryThumbs;
galleryThumbs.params.control = galleryTop;
```

a working example of the problem is here: http://jsfiddle.net/00gz8gLd/12/

I didn't expect the result with loop: true, when I set it to false, the slider works great.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

for gallery-top:

```
loopedSlides: $('.gallery-top .swiper-wrapper .swiper-slide').length
```

for gallery-thumbs:

```
loopedSlides: $('.gallery-thumbs .swiper-wrapper .swiper-slide').length
```